# Send text "http" over python socket

Tags: python, sockets, http, browser, response

I am trying to create a HTTP server using python. The thing is I am getting everything to work except for sending a response message; if the message has a text `http`, the `send()` doesn't work.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK text/html')
```

Here are the others I tried:

```
connectionSocket.send(''.join('%s 200 OK text/html' % ('HTTP/1.1')))
connectionSocket.send('%s 200 OK text/html' % ('HTTP/1.1'))
msg = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK text/html'
for i in range(0, len(msg))
    connectionSocket.send(msg[i])
```

The only thing that seems to work is entity-fying the any of the character in `HTTP`, like

```
connectionSocket.send('&#72;TTP/1.1 200 OK text/html')
```

Where `&#72;` is equivalent to `H`. Otherwise the browser doesn't display the header received from the python server socket.

The problem also goes when I am trying to send a `404 Message` down the socket. The other contents are displayed, however, like a html file sent through the socket.

I want to know is there a proper way to do it? Because, if the client is not a browser, the html entity will not be understood.

Thanks in advance

Update:

Code:

```
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1240))
serverSocket.listen(1);

while True:
  print 'Ready to serve...'
  connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
  try:
    message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    filename = message.split()[1]
    f = open(filename[1:])
    outputdata = f.read()

    #Send one HTTP header line into socket
    connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK text/html') ## this is not working

    #Send the content of the requested file to the client
    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
    connectionSocket.close()

  except IOError:
    connectionSocket.send('&#72;TTP/1.1 404 File not found') ## this is not working
    connectionSocket.close();
```

serverSocket.close()

Screenshots:

Text as 'HTTP/1.1 ...'

[image]

[image]

Text as 'HTTP/1.1 ...'

[image]

[image]

HTML Code of hello.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Python</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I find hard to believe that the string `http` is the source of the problem that the socket is not able to send.

Comment: @PauloBu That's what I first thought, but, the other elements are displayed correctly. The code sends the html data read from the file and the browser displays it properly, all except for the http header.

Comment: But the browser is not suppose to show the http header isn't it?

Comment: Please provide enough information to reproduce the problem.  Tell us which libraries etc. you are using.

Comment: The valid HTTP is stripped out by the browser - this is how the browser communicates with the server. If you are seeing rendered html, then it is likely working

Comment: @PeterGibson I understand but the requirement is to display the http header. But when the client is from other sources, say, command line, then the header is not properly received? The command line client also doesn't display the header text!!

Comment: Please edit the post to include the problem you are trying to solve, and a SSCCE http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: What do you mean by "the requirement is to display the http header"? What command line client are you referring to? Both `wget` and `curl` will strip the HTTP header and just give you the HTML document back

Comment: @PeterGibson 1: the requirement for the program is to display the received header. 2: the command line client is "command line" "client" where client is a person and command line is the interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not returning a correctly formed HTTP response. Your line

```
connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK text/html') ## this is not working
```

is not even terminated by a newline, then immediately followed by the content of your file. Protocols like HTTP specify fairly rigorously what must be sent, and I find it little short of miraculous that you saw anything at all in your browser.

Try something like:

```
connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n')
```

This is the start of a correctly-formed HTTP 1.1 response with a primary response line and a single header. The double newline terminates the headers, preparing the client to read the content that follows.

http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/ is one of many approachable ways to learn a bit more about the protocol you have chosen to use. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that worked pretty well. I used `connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1\n\n 200 OK Content-Type: text/html');` and it displayed everything from 200 to text/html. However, it didn't display the HTTP/1.1, as you guys said, it is stripped out.

Comment: The `"\n\n"` is terminating the HTTP response early. Take a look at http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPResponseMessageFormat.htm to discover what you should be sending - it's very important to stick to the correct format here, you cannot just make it up as you go along, and a little reading will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `connectionSocket` you are using (which module, library, etc.) but if this thing is already part of a HTTP-related routine, it might well be that it already sends the necessary `HTTP` line without your doing.  Yours then might disturb the process.

The quoted version (`&#72;TTP`...) probably is not recognized by the HTTP protocol in the browser (I think that quoting is only recognized and interpreted in higher layers of the OSI stack) and therefore does not have the same effect.

Comment: The library is `socket`. `from socket import *`. And can you be more clear please, I can't understand whether you are saying the format is correct or not. "The quoted version (&#72;TTP...) probably is not recognized by the HTTP protocol in the browser" -- the quoted version is what works. Others dont.

Comment: `connection_socket` is the socket returned by an `accept()` call in the code. This is not the issue.

Comment: Yeah, my idea was wrong, obviously, if you are using `socket.socket` directly.  I thought giving the `HTTP` explicitly additionally to an implicit `HTTP` the presumed underlying library produces automatically (which is of course not the case with `socket.socket`) would lead to a doubling and thus to a problem.  Then giving it in a quoted form explicitly would have left the implicit part intact and thus cloaked the problem.  You didn't say so right away, but now I guess that _without_ the quoted version (i.e. also without an unquoted version) it also doesn't work.  Am I right?